# Why does this on() function fire without mousemove?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, eventhandler

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('.map').mousedown(function () {
    $(this).on("mousemove", updateCoords);
});
$(window).mouseup(function () {
    $(".map").off("mousemove");
});

function updateCoords() {
    alert();
}
```

For some reason, `updateCoords()` is fired on `.map` click, not on click AND drag.  Also, the `off()` function does not work as expected.  After `.map` has been clicked on, AND I've released the mouse, it still fires `updateCoords()` on JUST mouseover.  Why is this?

```js
$('.map').mousedown(function() {
  $(this).on("mousemove", updateCoords);
});
$(window).mouseup(function() {
  $(".map").off("mousemove");
});

function updateCoords() {
  alert();
}
```

```css
.map {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="map"></div>
```

Comment: `alert()` is a really terrible way to debug something like this.

Comment: [Your code seems to work just fine if you don't put an `alert()` in the middle of it.](http://jsfiddle.net/2a0rw7kb/)  The `alert()` causes you to shift focus to the popup, which is a separate window that forces the browser window to lose focus.